# Reconstructing the original data from detrended data -- Python

Tags: python, signals, time-series

I have obtained the detrended data from the following python code:

```
Detrended_Data = signal.detrend(Original_Data)
```

Is there a function in python wherein the "Original_Data" can be reconstructed using the "Detrended_Data" and some "correction factor"?

Comment: What exactly does your `detrend` function do to the data?

Comment: This is what I meant by de-trending [link](http://blog.ouseful.info/2011/01/15/matplotlib-detrending-time-series-data/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to [scipy.signal.detrend](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.detrend.html)? If so, the answer is no -- there is no (and can never be an) un-detrend function. `detrend` maps many arrays to the same array. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)    
assert np.allclose(signal.detrend(t), signal.detrend(2*t))
```

If there were an `undetrend` function, it would have to map `signal.detrend(t)` back to `t`, and also map `signal.detrend(2*t)` back to `2*t`. That's impossible, since `signal.detrend(t)` is the same array as `signal.detrend(2*t)`.

Comment: Is it the same case even with mlab.detrend_linear()?

Comment: That's not the question you should be asking. The real question should be, how can I figure this out for myself? The answer will be more rewarding, and if you apply that attitude in general, you can go much farther...

Comment: I have figured out myself a few more things about this topic after a week of work. Thank you very much for the advise. What you have suggested is in general pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use `numpy` to trend your data. That wouldn't properly give you the original data but it would make less 'noisy'.

[Read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939901/average-trend-curve-for-data-points-in-python) as it goes much more in detail into this.